# How to launch electron app on windows written in `TypeScript`?

Tags: typescript, electron

I have an electron app in `TypeScript`. And I use the command `electron ./src/electron.ts` to launch the electron window. It works fine on Mac but doesn't work on windows.

[image]

I don't have any electron configuration. 
The line about above error is:

```
let mainWindow: any;
```

It seems the syntax is not compiled on windows. How can I make it work on windows?

The full source code in `src/electron.ts` is:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow: any;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On OS X it"s common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: you must run typescript compiler to create javascript file and let electron run javascript file.

Comment: why does it work on `Mac` not `windows`?